# If the Tonegawa anime is supposed to be a prequel to Kaiji that is set in the 90s, how come it features modern things?

Tags: kaiji, mr-tonegawa-middle-management-blues

*Mr. Tonegawa: Middle Management Blues* is supposed to be a prequel to *Kaiji* series that is set in the 90s. However, the anime features modern things, for example: smartphones, vaping, apps like Yelp.

How come such things exist in the series?

Comment: This is also noted on [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E9%96%93%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86%E9%8C%B2%E3%83%88%E3%83%8D%E3%82%AC%E3%83%AF#%E6%A6%82%E8%A6%81) without any explanation: 時間軸としては『賭博黙示録カイジ』以前（1996年以前）に当たるが、作品内に登場する各種事物は連載中の現在と同じく2010年代のものになっている。 (While the time period is set before *Kaiji* (before 1996), the work introduced things from the same period of the serialization, which is around year 2010s, the current time period)